# OpenSSL error while performing yarn install

Tags: react-native, openssl, yarnpkg

Receive following error message time to time while I'm performing a yarn installation. It does not happen everytime , but it can be pretty consistent a few rounds and annoying when it does.

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/jsc-android/-/jsc-android-245459.0.0.tgz: 4441032128:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:677:
```

or this

```
https://registry.yarnpkg.com/hermes-engine/-/hermes-engine-0.2.1.tgz: 4382041536:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:677:
```

My routine of yarn installation

1. Yarn cache clean
2. Yarn install

Also to mention, I need to connect VPN while performing yarn install. Could this be a connection issue?

Comment: This look very much like a VPN issue, do you use artifactory or something similar ?

Comment: not exactly, but we do have private repo for dependencies.. hence vpn is required when pulling then. Are suspecting VPN connection causing this issue?